# Is "docker start" completely resume all running service started by "docker run"

Tags: docker

The command `docker run` is used to create container from image and make container running. When calling `docker run` I can pass `CMD` to tell docker to run some service at startup.

But when I call `docker stop` to stop the running container and then call `docker start`, does it run the same with the above `docker run`, for example, does it start all service the same as `docker run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker client is a convenience wrapper for many calls to the Docker API.

Docker run will :

1. Attempt to create the container
2. If the dockerimage isnt found, it will attempt to pull it
3. If the image is pulled successfully, it will then create the container
4. Once the container is created, it will then call Docker start on the new container

The short answer to your question is: Docker stop is the opposite of the Docker Start command. Docker run calls docker start at the end, but it also does a bunch of other things.

Docker run will always try and create a new container, and throw an error if the container name already exists. Docker start can be used to manually start an existing container. (you could also look into the "docker restart" command, which I believe calls docker stop and then docker start.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I notice that when I run `docker run` I can override the entrypoint and cmd. Are there any similar way to do like this with an exists container when I run `docker start`. Thanks so much!